# Arrows indicating relationships between classes are missing in BlueJ

Tags: java, bluej

Now I am using BlueJ to write some Java programs with my classmate. However, when I get my classmate source code to edit. Some arrows illustrating the relationship between classes are disappeared in my computer. How to fix the problem?

[image]